# Check if polynomial is in factored form, without factoring

Tags: functions, polynomials, algorithm, algebra, factorization

I have a large list `list` of integer polynomials, all of which are the output of `Factor`. So my list looks something like this: `{... x^2 + 1, (-1 + x)(x^2 + x + 1) ...}`

Now I want to do further analysis of the reducible elements of `list`. The problem is that I do not want to check each polynomial again by `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` because I already know which are irreducible (they are the ones which are not factored.)

**Q:** What efficient way is there to check if a polynomial is in factored form? I.e. a function `isF` such that `isF[(-1 + x)(1 + x + x^2)]` returns `True` but `isF[-1 + x^3]` and `isF[1 + x + x^2]` return `False`. I suppose `isF` could simply check if `(` appears in its input, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check whether the `Head` of the expression is `Plus`, which is associated with a non-factored polynomial:

```
list = {  1 + x^2,
        (-1 + x) (1 + x + x^2),
        (1 + x)^2,
        2 (2 + x + x^2), 
        2 (2 + x)^2
       };

ClearAll[isF]
isF[Times[_Integer, poly_]] := isF[poly]
isF[poly_] := Head[poly] =!= Plus
SetAttributes[isF, Listable]

isF@list

(* Out: {False, True, True, False, True} *)
```

Comment: What about something like the output of `Factor[2 x + 2 x^2 + 4]`?

Comment: @Carl Good point. I added a definition to handle that.